# where to call next in middleware

Tags: express

Below is a bodyParser middleware I came across while learning express.js basics.

I have indicated in below code where I incorrectly called next() initially which caused req.body to be undefined. I later moved to the correct line (inside the "req.on ('data')" block and it started working correctly. But I dont understand why it doesn't work if I call it outside the "req.on ('data')" block

```
const bodyParser = (req,res,next) => {
    if (req.method === 'POST'){
    req.on('data', data=> {
        const parsed = data.toString('UTF8').split('&'); 
        //console.log(parsed);
        const formdata = {};
        for (let parts of parsed){
            //console.log(parts);
            const [key, value] = parts.split('=');
            formdata[key] = value;
        }
        req.body = formdata;
        console.log(formdata);
        next();
     });
     // next() **** initally placed here which was causing req.body to be undefined.
    }
    else{
        next();
    }   
};
```

Comment: In the original position, next() runs right away, after the on data callback is attached, but before it's invoked.  The only place it can be where you know it will run after the data has appeared is within the on data callback.

Comment: ya I understand it now!! Thank you so much :)